# CCC pieChart visualization

Tags: jfreechart, mdx, pie-chart, ccc

I'm moving from JfreeChart to CCC. I'm able to show a CCC chart using a MDX query.
I have a problem:  what I have to change in my MDX query which allowed to show a pie chart in JfreeChart component, but not in CCC one? The query is the following:

```
with member [Measures].[Total] as '([DIM_X].[A], [Measures].[COUNT])' 
     member [Measures].[Perc] as '([Measures].[COUNT] * 100) / [Measures].[Total]' 
     set [Percent over threshold] as 'Filter([DIM_X].[A].Children, [Measures].[Perc] >= 4)' 
     member [DIM_X].[Others] as 'Aggregate({Filter([DIM_X].[A].Children, [Measures].[Perc] < 4)})' 
select NON EMPTY {[Measures].[COUNT]} ON COLUMNS, 
NON EMPTY {[Percent over threshold],[DIM_X].[Others]} ON ROWS 
from [CUBE]
```

Why the result set of this query is shown in a pie chart in the JFreeChart component and not in CCC one?
Another detail: in the CCC component I'm able to show the result set of the posted query Line or Bar chart.

Comment: Maybe you should retag your question to include CCC. I know neither of the chart engines you mention, and have no idea what their requirements are for the result of the query.

Comment: The query is invalid MDX:  member `[DIM_ZONA].[Others]` should be in dimension `[DIM_X]`, not `[DIM_ZONA]`.

Comment: Yes,Frank, but there isn't any tag like CCC or Community Chart Component. For the second question there was a mistake. THANKS

Comment: @FrankPl, could you kindly contribute a wiki excerpt to the "ccc" tag?  Perhaps consider giving it a proper name instead of a TLA?